# In J2ME, How to resize StringItem according to its content

Tags: java-me, lcdui

I am developing Location based J2ME app for my final year project. In that I have created an array of StringItem in **Appearance mode Item.BUTTON** which displaying **Place name & address** in its Text area,returning this results from Google Places API. The length & content of the place name & address return by Places API is not fixed. That's why sometimes entire Place name & address fits in StringItem's by default size & sometimes it get over limit and only shows place name because of long place name.

I set the StringItem size by this code  `ResultStrItem[i].setPreferredSize(ResultStrItem[i].getPreferredWidth(),       ResultStrItem[i].getPreferredHeight());`

But, it is not giving me desire result.. What should I do... plzz suggest me as soon as possible....